# Почему опять ошибка с загрузкой файлов?

Tags: php, yii2

Пытаюсь организовать загрузку файла `xlsx`. 
**Контролер:**

```
public function actionExcelparser(){
        $execelparser= new ParsersExcel();

        if ($execelparser->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){
            $execelparser->files = UploadedFile::getInstance($execelparser, 'files');
            $years=date('Y');
            $mounts=date('m');
            $path='files';
            foreach ($execelparser->files as $file) {
                $files_to = TransliteratorHelper::process($file->name, '', 'en');
                if ($execelparser->upload($path,$years,$mounts,$files_to)) {
                    $data = \moonland\phpexcel\Excel::import(Yii::getAlias('@frontend/web/').$path.'/'.$years.'/'.$mounts.'/'.$files_to);
                }
            }
                return $this->render('excelparser',[
                        'data'=>$data
                ]);
        }else{
            return $this->render('excelparser', [
                'model'     => $execelparser
            ]);
        }
    }
```

**Модель:**

```
<?php
namespace backend\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use backend\models\Parsers;


class ParsersExcel extends Model{
   public $files;
   //public $excel;
  public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['files'], 'file','skipOnEmpty' => true, 'extensions' => 'xls, xlsx'],
        ];
    }
    public function upload($path,$years,$mounts,$files_to){
        if ($this->validate()) {
            if (file_exists(Yii::getAlias('@frontend/web/').$path.'/'.$years.'/'.$mounts.'/')) {
            } else {
                mkdir(Yii::getAlias('@frontend/web/').$path.'/'.$years.'/'.$mounts.'/', 0775, true);
            }
            $this->files->saveAs(Yii::getAlias('@frontend/web/').$path.'/'.$years.'/'.$mounts.'/'.$files_to);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**Вот такую ошибку он мне выдает:**

> move_uploaded_file(): The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory

Подскажите, почему, и как правильно организовать загрузку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка говорит о том, что вы передаёте параметром не файл, куда сохранить, а директорию.
Включите ошибки и станет более понятно.

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL ^E_NOTICE);
```

Скорее всего ошибка заключается в этой строчке

```
$this->files->saveAs(Yii::getAlias('@frontend/web/').$path.'/'.$years.'/'.$mounts.'/'.$files_to);
```

Вы передаёте путь к папке. А это значит переменная $files_to пустая или с таким же названием есть директория.